# How to unselect items in kendo listview

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to unselect an item after the user selects it.
Basically I have the listview in a window and once the user selects it, I wanna get the item the user selected then do something with the data of that item and then unselect everything in the listview because next time the window is brought up I want it to be a fresh list (unselected items)
here is what i have so far

```
function listViewchanged(e) {

    var ds = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
    var index = ds.select().index();
    var dataItem = ds.dataSource.view()[index];

    closeWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.clearSelecton() is method you need but code like this:

```
$("#listView").kendoListView({
    change: function(e){
         e.sender.clearSelection();
    }
});
```

gonna make infinite loop because .clearSelection() triggers 'chage' event. What you can do is clear selection on window.open() event or just hide selected item via JS:

```
function listViewchanged(e) {
    var ds = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
    var index = ds.select().index();
    var dataItem = ds.dataSource.view()[index];
    ds.element.find('.k-state-selected').removeClass('k-state-selected');
    closeWindow();
}
```

One more think. If you use widget in event that it's triggering I recommend to use .sender property from event argument. So the final code is:

```
function listViewchanged(e) {
    var index = e.sender.select().index();
    var dataItem = e.sender.dataSource.view()[index];
    e.sender.element.find('.k-state-selected').removeClass('k-state-selected');
    closeWindow();
}
```